# Windows Azure Ubuntu - 500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd error while making an FTP connection

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, azure

I have created a VM on Windows Azure and running Ubuntu on that I have been able to successfully communicate using the http protocol on port 80

However, I am not able to make a successful FTP connection. Here is what I have done so

- Created an End Point with both public and private port as 21
- Installed vsftp on the server
- Made the config changes in vsftpd.conf; local_enable=YES, write_enable=YES

Now when I try to make a normal FTP connection on Filezilla, I have and error which says500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd

Can someone please let me know what I am missing

Help would be greatly appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading to the latest version or try the workaround [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=845980#c12)

Answer (score 1):

I also get error when connecting to FTP:

```
500 OOPS: prctl PR_SET_SECCOMP failed
500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd
```

The problem originates from FTP server vsftpd it self, so add this line to `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file:

```
seccomp_sandbox=NO
```

and restart FTP server:

```
$sudo service vsftpd restart
```